# Renderscript Greyscale not quite working

Tags: renderscript

This is my renderscript code for now:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.apps.foo.bar)

rs_allocation inPixels;

    uchar4 RS_KERNEL root(uchar4 in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {

      uchar4 pixel = in.rgba;

      pixel.r = (pixel.r + pixel.g + pixel.b)/3;
      pixel.g = (pixel.r + pixel.g + pixel.b)/3;
      pixel.b = (pixel.r + pixel.g + pixel.b)/3;

      return pixel;
    }
```

My phone shows a "greyscaled" picture. I say "grayscaled" because red for example, is still kinda red...It is gray-ish but you can still see that is red. I know I can use more sophisticated methods, but I would like to stick to the simple one for now.

I would like to know if my renderscript code is wrong. Should I be converting the `char` to another type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a temporary variable to hold the result as you compute it. Otherwise, in the first line you're modifying `pixel.r`, and in the very next one you are using it to calculate `pixel.g`. No wonder you get artifacts.

Also, don't forget to assign the alpha value to avoid surprises with "invisible" output.

Answer (score 0):

Also I would recommend not to use equal weights for r, g and b but the weights as below. See e.g. http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/08/24/algorithms-convert-color-grayscale/

```
char4 __attribute__((kernel)) gray(uchar4 in) {
uchar4 out;
float gr= 0.2125*in.r + 0.7154*in.g + 0.0721*in.b;
   out.r = out.g = out.b = gr;
   out.a = in.a;
return out;
}
```